# A function that returns the largest number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Create a function called largest that accepts an array of numbers and returns the largest number.

I created the function largest. I made a for loop to check for the largest number in the array.

```js
function largest(a){
  const num = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i] >= num){
      num = a[i];
      return num;
    }
  }
}
module.exports.largest = largest;
```

The code does not work.

Comment: Doesn't work how? What happens?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant array

Comment: why do you return as soon as you find a number greater than 0?

Comment: `return num;` <-- so what do you think this does? You exit the function after the first time it enters into the if. And hopefully your biggest number is greater than zero. `largest([-3, -2, -1])`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: Don't return after checking just the first number, return after `for` loop completes. Every number in the array must be checked to see if it is the largest.

Comment: `return Math.max(...a);`

Comment: define num as let and return num at end of function

Comment: from the [`Math.max` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Examples):  `module.exports.largest = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) =>Math.max(a, b));`

Comment: One can also just use `Math.max()` directly as in `Math.max(...array)` or in older versions of JS, `Math.max.apply(Math, array)`.

Answer (score 1):

You marked your `num` variable as a constant. This means it is not going to update with your comparisons. Do `let num = 0;` instead.

Also, take a look at your scoping. Inside your if statement you check the first elemnt in that array, compare it with `num` which is initially 0, than immediately return. You need to put your return statement outside of the scope of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you look at your developer tools console you will see this error:

> TypeError: invalid assignment to const `num`

It relates to this line:

```
num = a[i];
```

You've defined `num` with `const num = 0` but a variable defined with `const` cannot be changed later (hence the error) so your definition should use `let` instead.

Second, once that code doesn't cause the error, is the issue that your function is returning too early. Your return is occuring in the loop - once you've done the first check you return and the loop doesn't progress any further. So you move your return to the line *after* the loop instead to ensure all the iterations run.

```js
function largest(a){
  let num = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i] >= num){
      num = a[i];
    }
  }
  return num;
}

const arr = [1, 141, 23, 10, 9, 92];
console.log(largest(arr));
```

There are a couple of shortcuts to find the largest number in an array that you use that are popular:

This first one [`spreads`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) out the array so that [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) can use it.

```js
const arr = [1, 141, 23, 10, 9, 92];
console.log(Math.max(...arr));
```

Alternatively you can sort the array smallest to largest number and then pop off the last element.

```js
const arr = [1, 141, 23, 10, 9, 92];
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a > b).pop());
```

Comment: I would just _love_ to know the explanation for that downvote.